# calculation with && and OR

Tags: javascript, pdf

I try to do the following calculation in JavaScript in a PDF

If the field is X => 0 and <= 5 then the field Z = (X * field field Y) / 100

I can not build correctly. I am a beginner, can you help me? Thank you

```
my code:

var taux = this.getField("EstimationTauxAnciennete").value;

var salaire = this.getField("SalaireMensuel ").value;

if( taux >= 0 && <=1 ) event.value = (salaire * 3)/100; 

else if ( taux >= 2 && <=5 ) event.value = (salaire * 6)/100;

else event.value = 0;
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "X => 0 and <= 5"m think more as "X >= 0 and X <= 5".

```
if(x >= 0 && x <= 5)
{
    z = (x * y) / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: if(x >= 0 || x <= 5)   this would be the OR statement, same key as \ but with SHIFT for |, this is not an I (upper case eye), or l (lower case L) , or a 1 (number one)

Comment: Heads up: if clausule shoud be like `if(a > 0) { ... } else if (b > 0) { ...} else { ... }`

Comment: Thank you for all your guidance helped me, in fact the code above works